# Wix Bootstrapper setup.exe never starts and log reads Failed to load theme controls

Tags: wix, themes, bootstrapper, burn, wix3

***Environment***

Using a Bootstrapper project in Visual Studio 2012/Visual Studio 2013

Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

WixToolset 3.8

***Details***

Setup.exe never runs

The log file in AppData/Local/Temp/[WixBundleName][DateTime].log reads "Error 0x8007000d: Failed to load theme controls."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found that editing the *Theme/Image[@ImageFile*] value to anything other than **Logo.png** with cause the described error.

Changing the value back to **Logo.png** reverses the error.

Setting the value in *Wix/Bundle/bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication[@LogoFile]* appropriately changes the image and does not cause the setup.exe to produce an error.

**Note** I downloaded and used the default theme for [HyperlinkLicense](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/Resources/HyperlinkTheme.xml) for my custom template with only change being the ImageFile attribute. It is improbable that this was a result of ill-formed xml.

Comment: JDennis, THANK YOU DO MUCH!!!
I've spent hours searching for clue, and here you are!

Comment: @MarcusUA Glad to help! Seems like an arbitrary error that is easy to make and hard to find.

Comment: found some more info (needed to add 2 images on one page)
One can add images with other names, just use <PayLoad>

     <Payload SourceFile="Resources\Logo_2.png" />

Comment: If SO would let me, I'd upvote that comment from @MarcusUA a million times.

Comment: I had same error for HyperlinkSidebarTheme theme. because of missing  <Payload SourceFile="logoside.png" />

Answer (score 1):

In addition to JDennis' answer:
If you want to change the image, you should not modify the theme file. You need to define LogoFile attribute of the bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication element in your bundle:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
                  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="myLogo.png" ThemeFile="myHyperlinkTheme.xml" LocalizationFile="myHyperlinkTheme.wxl" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```